# How to access and loop through an array in a hash

Tags: arrays, loops, perl, hash, hashmap

I am just starting out with Perl programming and I have a question I have been trying to solve.

If I have a config:

```
my %config = (
'repos'   => {
    'duosecurity' => [
        'duo_unix.x86_64',
    ],

    #'puppet'      => [
        #   'puppet-agent',
        #],

    'RHEL-77-x86_64' => [
        'perl-Data-Random.noarch',
    ]});
```

How can I access the array and loop though it at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach my $repo (keys %{$config{repos}}) {
    print "$repo\n";
    foreach my $list_ele (@{$config{repos}{$repo}}) {
        print "\t$list_ele \n";
    }
}
```

hopefully indicates to you how you can access it.